# How to write a double to a file in human-readable form and read the exact double back in?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

Is it possible to write an arbitrary double in human-readable form to a file and get **exactly**, all 64 bits the same double when reading it back in?

Of course, this is possible by writing the double as binary data, e.g.:

```
static void writedouble(FILE *fp, double d) {
    fwrite(&d, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
}
```

But that's not what I want. I want the `double` to be written in human-readable form, e.g. like so:

```
static void writedouble(FILE *fp, double d) {
    fprintf(fp, "%.14g", d);
}
```

And then read it again in, like so:

```
static void readdouble(FILE *fp, double *d) {
    fscanf(fp, "%.14g", d);
}
```

After that I want to test if both `double`s are the same, e.g.:

```
printf("Check: %d\n", memcmp(&in_double, &out_double, sizeof(double));
```

Is that possible at all or is it only possible to get the bit-exact `double` when storing it as binary data?

Comment: Can the human read binary? ;)

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: What happened when you tried? Are you just assuming that it will not work?

Comment: You already have the solution using fprintf/fscanf. What else do you want?

Comment: @klutt: I've tried it for `M_PI` and it doesn't work. The two doubles are not exactly the same, i.e. `memcmp` returns 1.

Comment: @John: I want a bit-exact copy, as stated in the OP.

Comment: I guess there's your answer. Change 14 to 16 to bring the precision up.

Comment: Is your requirement really to produce a human-readable numeral? Or is it to produce a human-readable and decimal numeral (would hexadecimal be okay)? Or is it to produce any representation of the `double` with printable characters (or some other subset of the character set) so that it can be written to a file that may be handled by various text-processing software and read back, even if a human cannot easily read it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: By human-readable I mean a decimal numeral like `3.14159265359` etc. Hexadecimal isn't ok. That would be a cheap trick to write the binary data as a 8 hexadecimal bytes :) I want a decimal numeral that the user can understand at first sight (and possibly change).

Comment: @Andreas: Writing the bytes that represent the value using hexadecimal and writing the value using hexadecimal are different things.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Ok, but I guess it's still not as easily editable as is a decimal number, isn't it?

Comment: @Andreas: It depends on your objective is, which was not clearly evident from your question. Your question does not say anything about editing the number. If the object were merely to get the data through some printable-characters-only format, then any encoding with printable characters would suffice. If the objective were for a human to be able to be able to easily read, speak, and/or write the data, then a variety of formats might suffice—anything breaking it into convenient units instead of “random” characters. But…

Comment: @Andreas: … if your objective is for a human to be able to conceptualize the value of the number, then a numeral format may be needed. Objectively, decimal and hexadecimal are equally useful for this purpose, except that most humans are more familiar with decimal. But sometimes hexadecimal is used, depending on the audience and the need—it is easier to generate and to parse and suffices for situations where humans rarely need to match it to decimal values. Certainly hexadecimal is as editable as decimal. All these variations are reasons why it is important to clearly state a question.

Comment: @Andreas: Even if you limited the format to decimal, there are questions about the format. For example, would scientific notation be okay? Some humans cannot read that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, I wasn't really clear in my OP. By human-readable I meant a decimal numeral... decimal numerals should be the canonical representation of floating point numbers AFAIK. It's all about serializing data structures to files and back. Scientific notation is ok because I think I can assume some basic knowledge of maths.

Comment: @Andreas: Decimal is not canonical and should not be for binary-based floating-point. And it is not “all about serializing data structures to files and back” because decimal is inefficient and error prone for that purpose when the format is not decimal based. As we saw in the answer when you accepted, it had an error in the required precision. If the goal is to serialize for writing to files and reading back, then C’s hexadecimal `%a` format is good for that. It is efficient and automatically provides enough precision to reproduce numbers, even if the floating-point format is not binary based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to write an arbitrary double in human-readable form to a file and get exactly, all 64 bits the same double when reading it back in?

Yes, of course it is, provided you use enough precision. A `double` has *at most* `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` decimal digits of precision, as defined in `float.h`, so the following program works just fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>

static void writedouble(FILE *fp, double d) {
    fprintf(fp, "%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, d);
}

static void readdouble(FILE *fp, double *d) {
    fscanf(fp, "%lg", d);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.txt", "w+");

    double x = M_PI; // Use pi, just as a test.
    double y;

    writedouble(fp, x);
    rewind(fp);
    readdouble(fp, &y);
    fclose(fp);

    // Check if the actual representation of the two values
    // in memory is exactly the same.
    assert(memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof(double)) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

The main difference between the above and your code is that:

1. The `printf` is called with a precision of `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` (17), not `14`.
2. The `scanf` is called without a precision modifier (since it is not needed nor supported), but with the `l` modifier, since (unlike `printf`) `scanf` distinguishes between `float` (`f`, `e`, `g`) and `double` (`lf`, `le`, `lg`).

Comment: This program fails for 18014398509481982. It writes “1.801439850948198e+16”, which is 18014398509481980, and the value produced by reading back is 18014398509481980, and the `assert` fails. A portable method would be `fprintf(fp, "%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, d);`. `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is defined in <float.h>, and it is 17 for IEEE-754 binary64.

Comment: The amount of information in the 53-bit significand of an IEEE-754 binary64 is actually less than 16 decimal digits; is is about 15.95 digits (log(2\*\*53)/log(10)). However, think about how many 1-unit-long bricks you need to cover the length of an object 15.95 units long. If you start the bricks at the beginning of the object, 16 will surely do it. But you do not have that choice—the powers of two fall in diverse locations relative to the powers of ten. For some significands, you are forced to start elsewhere. You need one brick to get to the start of the object and 16 more to finish it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ah, thanks so much, that's quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the `%a` format of `printf` and `scanf`.  It's text and 100% reversible, although it suffers somewhat in the human-readability department.